# how can i add click listener to each dynamically generated arrays of textviews in android?

Tags: android

I need to add a click event on each textview that is dynamically generated.

The textviews are in a form of array and I m adding textviews fetched from a json string.

Guide me on how to achieve it.

below is my code:

```
    Button b =(Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    starters = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    starters.setOnClickListener(this);

    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel1);

    itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        SingleContactActivity.class);

        in.putExtra(TAG_Name, name);

        startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    new Getitems().execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    switch(arg0.getId()){

    case R.id.textView1: 
    ontextview1click();
    break;

    case R.id.start:
        try {
            onbuttonclick();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    }
}

private void onbuttonclick() throws JSONException {
    TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[items.length()];
    TextView[] tx = new TextView[items.length()];

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

        String category = c.getString(TAG_Cat);
        tx[i] = new TextView(S1.this);
        tx[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tx[i].setText(category);

        tr[i] = new TableRow(S1.this);
        tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr[i].addView(tx[i],new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tl.addView(tr[i],new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}

private void ontextview1click() {

    if (key==0){
        key=1;
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }

        else if(key==1) {
        key=0;
        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

Comment: have a listview with textviews for the rows. then you can use setOnItemClickListener for lsitview

Comment: u mean I ll have to take another listview where ill have to add the tableRow in which my textviews are being generated dynamically?

Comment: i mean there is no need for a table. just use a custom lsitview

Comment: bt I need to add textviews to a layout so I have used a tablelayout instead of listview and in a listview is each item clickable?

Comment: yes you can click each row of the lsitview or individual textviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tx[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then in on click method

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {


        if(arg0==tx[i]){

        }
}
```

Comment: n what if I want to add different conditions to different textviews?will the above code work for it?

Comment: so should I add the above code in doInBackground() or the onClick() of button? because I need to display the data after the click event in the listview

Comment: I added it bt it says "i" should be declared final ! bt I is incremented so it wont be declared final. what can I do now?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {  change this line to 

for (i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) { 

now declare i as global variable